# Perform Ajax-based paging & sorting inside my WebGrid for asp.net mvc5 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, webgrid, razor-2

I was searching for a web grid that work well with asp.net mvc framework. Many jquery grids such as jqGrid, Datatables provide very powerful grids , but at the same time they do not support  html helpers, data annptation that are provided by asp.net mvc framework. However i find these two links which talk about the WebGrid which seems very suitable for asp.net mvc5 web applicatios [Link1](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1125/search-sort-paging-insert-update-and-delete-with-asp-net-mvc-and-bootstrap-modal-popup-part-1) & [Link2](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1126/search-sort-paging-insert-update-and-delete-with-asp-net-mvc-and-bootstrap-modal-popup-part-2) . But can anyone advice if i can modify the WebGrid provided in these links to have these two features:-

1. from the code in the two examples , doing a Paging or column sort will cause the current web page to re-load as the Index action method will return  full view instead of partial view. So is there a way to provide ajax-based paging and sorting?
2. Can i provide column-based filtering for the Grid, where a user will have the option to filter the grid based of certain column values?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Yes, it's possible to use use Ajax with WebGrid 2. Yes, this also can be done. Use `AjaxUpdateContainer`, take a look at this example : http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/18NI110113-Enhancing-WebGrid-with-ajax-in-MVC4.html